# MySQL ORDER BY "count(*) and 2 other parameters" from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have been struggling with this problem for about month..
Have been searching and reading many posts, but still can't figure out, how to make this work..

Basically: I got 2 database tables `fun_posts` and `fun_post_upvotes` And I want to

```
SELECT * 
FROM fun_posts 
ORDER BY (HOTTEST POSTS(MOST UPVOTED THIS WEEK))
```

This is my latest code, that won't work

```
SELECT * 
FROM fun_posts 
ORDER BY (SELECT count(*), image_id, date 
          FROM fun_post_upvotes 
          GROUP BY image_id 
          ORDER BY DATE(date) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) DESC, 
                   count(*) DESC, 
                   date DESC)
```

If I divide this line into 2 different `SELECT` functions, they work. I can select simple posts and I can select upvotes count ordered like I want.

But If I make them into one line like that, I get following error:

> #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

**EDIT NR 1:**

`fun_posts` table
[image]
`fun_post_upvotes` table
[image]

Problem with Answer that I checked:

Here, look how posts are ordered in my `select` function. (It selects like I want) 10->134->132->2->13

[image]

And here with given code (It selects image, but not in that order) 10->122->39->8->110

[image]

Comment: You need to use/add a `WHERE` clause, and a JOIN would be beneficial.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why? Can you please explain? Then It won't show "posts" who don't have any upvotes this week. And when divided into 2 seperate SELECTS, they are working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a join to do this

```
SELECT fp.*, fpu.`cnt`
FROM fun_posts fp
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT image_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM fun_post_upvotes
       WHERE `date` > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 day)
       GROUP BY image_id
     ) fpu ON ( fpu.image_id = fp.id )
ORDER BY fpu.cnt DESC, fp.`date` DESC, fp.`id` DESC;
```

It selects a list from `fun_post_upvotes` grouped by image_id and counts the amount of rows. That list is returned to the main query and matches (LEFT JOIN) on fp.id. The query will first show the item with the most upvotes in the past 7 days, than the least. If no upvotes are found, the result will still return them, but at the bottom in no specific order.

You can edit the order by, to obtain the items in the order you like.

Here a [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5ad9/2)

Comment: What does "fpu" mean? Did you mistaped it and It needed to be "fp"?

Comment: fpu is the name under which the result of the subquery is known within the query. So the shortname for fun_ports will be `fp` and the shortname for the joined table will be `fpu` (aka the result of the fun_post_upvotes query)

Comment: Sorry, can you please help me more? I checked As answered but found out that it won't work like i need.

Comment: put the structure of both sql table in your question, and i'll update my anwer

Comment: I have edited my Question. Hope you will understand.

Comment: I just removed "ORDER BY fpu.cnt DESC;" And it works like I want. Thank you very much! Appreciate that.